# How to search for a list of combinations of two columns in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a list of combinations from a table (First_Name and Start month of employment).

I need to be able to search the table and determine what entries in the table are not in the list.  Ex. (Mark, January exists but Mark, March doesn't.)

Is there a shorter way to do this than append every combination to the SQL?  This is a pretty long list out of a pretty large table.

Comment: [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: please share what you tried

Comment: Read this.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can `CROSS JOIN` employee names with list of months to create all possible combinations. `LEFT JOIN` for the rest:

```
SELECT
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT First_Name FROM t
) AS emp
CROSS JOIN (VALUES
    ('January'), ('February'), ('March'), ('April'), ('May'), ('June'),
    ('July'), ('August'), ('September'), ('October'), ('November'), ('December')
) mon(Month_Name)
LEFT JOIN t ON emp.First_Name = t.First_Name AND mon.Month_Name = t.Month_Name
WHERE t.PK IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use joins to a temporal table or equivalent expressions. Something like

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM (       SELECT 'Mike' AS name, 'March' AS month
        UNION  SELECT 'John' AS name, 'April' AS month) AS aux
  JOIN table t ON t.name = aux.name 
              AND t.month = aux.name
```

Of course it can be a literal temporary or standard table if you alredy have the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `left join` or `not exists` for this.  For instance:

```
select v.*
from (values ('Mark', 'January'), ('Mark', 'March')) v(name, mon)
where not exists (select 1
                  from t
                  where t.name = v.name and t.mon = v.mon
                 );
```